# Is there a Stack Exchange site to discuss and identify possible scam websites?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51

I'm currently facing a lot of possible scam websites in the area of cryptocurrency investments. But there are other areas on the Internet where a lot of scams happens, too. I would love to have a Stack Exchange community where I can search for and post possible scam websites to discuss them.

Would this make sense, or are there reasons not to have such kind of community on Stack Exchange? Or is there already a place for it?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it would work in our Q&A format.

Comment: I'm also afraid, that it leads to people trying to advertise legit websites. But maybe the community can find solutions for that.

Comment: My personal recommendations would be scamwarners.com and aa419.org where the universal reference base is held.

Answer (score 14):

> Would this make sense, or are there reasons not to have such kind of community on StackExchange? Or is there already a place for it?

There is no place for it, mostly because it doesn't make sense because communities on SE are not "hosts for discussion of", they're for questions and answers and building a library of useful information on a specific subject.

So, "discussing sites" wouldn't fit within the model. I also doubt a site where the only question you can ask goes like "Is site X a scam or legitimate" would work. There are more sites on the internet than people willing to answer those questions, most likely. I can give you the first 180 or so questions for free, by asking such a question about every site on the SE network itself.

As for having a site where you could 'search for' possible scam websites, I don't know who would want to do that. But some people have strange hobbies. I doubt linking to every scam website out there is going to have a good influence on Stack Exchange's reputation though.

If you want to know what to look out for to recognize scams, [several communities on the network already have such questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=recognize+scam+website+stack+exchange&oq=recognize+scam+website+stack+exchange). There's no need for a new community.

Comment: Among the communities that work with such questions there's at least Travel (with [scams](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams)), Security ([scam](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scam)) and Personal Finance & Money ([scams](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams)). Between them, they have a couple hundred questions at least.

Comment: @Mast yes. And I know that e.g. on Personal Finance & Money, there seem to have been repeated efforts on their meta to find some sort of 'canonical' question/answer to questions asking 'Is thing X a scam'. So I would not advise OP or anyone else seeing the questions tagged 'scam' on those sites to go to any of these sites just to ask whether site X is a scam or not.